# Position dropdown menu under the button that triggers it

Tags: javascript, html, css, drop-down-menu

I'm trying to create a dropdown menu for easier navigation on a simple website. I've borrow a large amount of code from [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_dropdown.asp). A disclaimer is that I'm really bad at styling and js in general.

The problem is that when I add an additional button, the menu displays under the first button.

```js
function myFunction(a) {

  document.getElementById(a).classList.toggle("show");

}
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {
    var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
      var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
      if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
        openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```css
.dropbtn {
  background-color: #3498DB;
  color: white;
  padding: 16px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}


/* Dropdown button on hover & focus */

.dropbtn:hover,
.dropbtn:focus {
  background-color: #2980B9;
}


/* The container <div> - needed to position the dropdown content */

.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}


/* Dropdown Content (Hidden by Default) */

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}


/* Links inside the dropdown */

.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}


/* Change color of dropdown links on hover */

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd
}


/* Show the dropdown menu (use JS to add this class to the .dropdown-content container when the user clicks on the dropdown button) */

.show {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
  <button onclick="myFunction('myDropdown0')" class="dropbtn">Menu1</button>
  <div id="myDropdown0" class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="{% url 'App1:index' %}">choice1</a>
  </div>
  <button onclick="myFunction('myDropdown1')" class="dropbtn">Menu2</button>
  <div id="myDropdown1" class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="{% url 'App2:index' %}">Choice1</a>
    <a href="{% url 'App2:page2' %}">Choice2</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

It feels like there should be an easy way to edit this to take the position of the button pressed into account, but I'm unsure of how.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should update your `window.onclick` function and HTML `div` tag. One solution is to close all menu first, then open the menu.

Please try:

```js
function myFunction(a) {
  closeAllMenu();
        document.getElementById(a).classList.toggle("show");
}

function closeAllMenu(){//before show menu, close all menu first
        var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
        var i;
        for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
            var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
                openDropdown.classList.remove('show'); 
        }
}

window.onclick = function(event) { // click outside the menu, close menu
    if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {
        var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
        var i;
        for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
            var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
            if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
                openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```css
.dropbtn {
    background-color: #3498DB;
    color: white;
    padding: 16px;
    font-size: 16px;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

/* Dropdown button on hover & focus */
.dropbtn:hover, .dropbtn:focus {
    background-color: #2980B9;
}

/* The container <div> - needed to position the dropdown content */
.dropdown {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

/* Dropdown Content (Hidden by Default) */
.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 1;
}

/* Links inside the dropdown */
.dropdown-content a {
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
}

/* Change color of dropdown links on hover */
.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #ddd}

/* Show the dropdown menu (use JS to add this class to the .dropdown-content container when the user clicks on the dropdown button) */
.show {display:block;}
```

```html
 <div class="dropdown">
  <button onclick="myFunction('myDropdown0')" class="dropbtn">Menu1</button>
  <div id="myDropdown0" class="dropdown-content">
   <a href="{% url 'App1:index' %}">choice1</a>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="dropdown">
  <button onclick="myFunction('myDropdown1')" class="dropbtn">Menu2</button>
  <div id="myDropdown1" class="dropdown-content">
   <a href="{% url 'App2:index' %}">Choice1</a>
   <a href="{% url 'App2:page2' %}">Choice2</a>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Shouldn't clicking on another button also close the previously opened button? Besides that, a clean fix.

Comment: Please try to update your function in window.onclick

Comment: Your function in window.onclick will only close the menu when you click outside the button.So if you click another button, it will do nothing.

Comment: Yeah, that was another question I was going to take a stab at after this one, since it's solved now, do you have any suggestions on how one might do that?

Comment: As far as I can see it has been fixed by @samchu

Answer (score 0):

I try to simply change the if condition to `if (event.target.matches('.dropbtn'))` in [js function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50306788/9684338)

But it will close all menu after button click.

You can try another solution used by only one js function.

```js
window.onclick = function(event) {
    // click outside the menu, close menu
    var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
        var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
        if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
            openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
        }
    }
    if(event.target.matches('.dropbtn')){
  var res = event.target.id.split("-");// get the first part before "-"
  document.getElementById(res[0]).classList.toggle("show");
 }
}
```

```css
.dropbtn {
    background-color: #3498DB;
    color: white;
    padding: 16px;
    font-size: 16px;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

/* Dropdown button on hover & focus */
.dropbtn:hover, .dropbtn:focus {
    background-color: #2980B9;
}

/* The container <div> - needed to position the dropdown content */
.dropdown {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

/* Dropdown Content (Hidden by Default) */
.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 1;
}

/* Links inside the dropdown */
.dropdown-content a {
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
}

/* Change color of dropdown links on hover */
.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #ddd}

/* Show the dropdown menu (use JS to add this class to the .dropdown-content container when the user clicks on the dropdown button) */
.show {display:block;}
```

```html
 <div class="dropdown">
  <button id="myDropdown0-btn" class="dropbtn">Menu1</button>
  <div id="myDropdown0" class="dropdown-content">
   <a href="{% url 'App1:index' %}">choice1</a>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="dropdown">
  <button id="myDropdown1-btn" class="dropbtn">Menu2</button>
  <div id="myDropdown1" class="dropdown-content">
   <a href="{% url 'App2:index' %}">Choice1</a>
   <a href="{% url 'App2:page2' %}">Choice2</a>
  </div>
 </div>
```